# Get current Website domain name in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a quick question regarding AJAX requests and Posts.

Let's say I have a website called www.mysite.com and I make this AJAX post:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'www.mysite.com/post.php',
data: {msg:"Hello world"},
cache: false,
success: function(response){
    alert(response);
}
```

Ok now this works perfectly fine, but let's say I wanna change my domain name, to something more exciting, like www.myamazingwebsite.jeff I'd need to replace that URL in every AJAX request/post I ever made. That can become very annoying.

Isn't there a variable like %CurDomain or %CurPath to get the current domain name or the current path to the JS file the AJAX post is being made in?

That would allow me to NOT change those URLs

Comment: ...just leave the domain part out.

Comment: `url: 'post.php',` works on `good.com` and `bad.com` and also `ugly.com`

Comment: Yeah but that only works with subfiles. If the script calling that is in www.mysite.com/scripts/script.js that will call www.mysite.com/scripts/post.php, which is not what I want

Comment: `url: '/post.php'` calls mysite.com/post.php.

Comment: @Skymen No, if you leave the domain off, it will be autonatically added. So leave it off and the code will work on any domain you move the code to

Comment: Cool, thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.location.hostname` for the domain and  `document.location.pathname` for the path.

`document.location.href` can get the full URL.

So corresponding to your code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: document.location.href,
data: {msg:"Hello world"},
cache: false,
success: function(response){
    alert(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You may try this. In a separate js file say mysite.js, write var mysite="www.myamazingwebsite.jeff/"; Now include this file in all the js files making ajax calls as 
within your $.ajax({... write url: mysite + 'post.php',
so next time to change your domain name just change mysite in the mysite.js as mysite="www.mynesitename.jeff/"